# Response error from facebook using django

Tags: python, django, facebook

## This is my view file when i run it,it will show me error(Check the attach image). how to overcome with this problem.

```
def home(request):
   return HttpResponse('''
       Login with <a href="login/">Facebook</a>.<br />
   ''')

def facebook_login(request,provider_name):
   params = {
       'scope': [settings.FACEBOOK_APP_SCOPE],
       'client_id': settings.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
       'redirect_uri': settings.SITE_URL + '/auth/facebook/callback'
   }
   url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?"   + urllib.urlencode(params)
   print url
   return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

This is the error that i got:

```
error=invalid_scope&error_description=Unsupported+scope%3A+%27%5B%27public_profile%27%5D%27.+Supported+scopes%3A+ads_management+ads_read+email+manage_notifications+manage_pages+offline_access+publish_actions+read_friendlists+read_insights+read_mailbox+read_page_mailboxes+read_stream+rsvp_event+user_about_me+user_activities+user_birthday+user_education_history+user_events+user_friends+user_games_activity+user_groups+user_hometown+user_interests+user_likes+user_location+user_photos+user_relationship_details+user_relationships+user_religion_politics+user_status+user_videos+user_website+user_work_history
```

Comment: What is the value of `FACEBOOK_APP_SCOPE` in your `settings.py`?

Comment: FACEBOOK_APP_SCOPE='public_profile'